# Auto- vs ManualResetEvent, differences

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I read about event, which allow me to wait for other thread: `AutoResetEvent` and `ManualResetEvent`.

What are the differences between these two classes? Which class is better for a highly concurrent program?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It very clearly explains the differences. Neither is better or worse than the other, they are meant for different things.

Comment: The question is too vague to answer. Regarding your first question: What part of the documentation is unclear? Regarding your second question: if I handed you two screwdrivers and asked you which one was "better" I hope you'd say "the one that fits the screw you need to drive".

Comment: _"the one that fits the screw you need to drive"_ - that's pure gold! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in what happens when the event is signaled (set).

- the manual-reset event will stay signaled until your explicitly reset it again
- the auto-reset event will automatically get reset (unsignaled) once the first thread waiting for it gets awaken

In general I find it easier to work with manual reset events because in most cases it is a bit more straight-forward to determine the state of the event at any given time.

That said there are cases when the behavior of the auto-reset event lends itself better to achieving synchronization because you are guaranteed that **only one** of the waiting threads will be signaled. So if you have a producer/multiple-consumers scenario where any, but only, one consumer should be signaled you should consider the auto-reset event.